# iOS SDK and values in custom initializers?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Say I have a custom initializer for a class:

```
- (id) initWithBlah:(NSString *)blah{
    // do random stuff with blah and return self
}
```

How would I access the string assigned to "blah" in another method?

```
- (void) getBlah {
    // get value of blah here from initializer
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting blah to a property, and then xcode would generate getters and setters for it.

Comment: You mean the compiler would generate them...

Answer (score 0):

Read up on properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html